# Samsung tablet & an USB RFID reader (powered through USB). Can I use an "USB Y cable"?

Tags: usb

Can I use an USB Y cable to charge the tablet and to connect tablet to the RFID reader at the other end?Currently works fine when both are connected directly but solution is not sustainable, the tablet is not charging in the same time.

If you know other fast & cheap solutions, please share.

Thanks a lot in advance for your support!

Comment: If it works already;  Why are you asking if it will work?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is a max power draw per USB port.

When you try this two things can happen:

1. Both try to use the data part and things fail.
2. At most one tries to use the data part but both draw power.

The specs assume max 500mW of current at +5v per USB 2 port (slightly more for USB3). If you exceed that then bad things can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can with SimulCharge technology. SimulCharge is a USB mode where tablet is placed into OTG/Host Mode but has its battery simultaneously charged. This technology is only available for Samsung Tablets. It allows for efficient power allocation to a tablet and peripherals. The only company that it uses (at least that I know) is LAVA. Their website (www.lavalink.com) has a lot of adapters that will support what you are asking for. They have a list also of Samsung tablet that supports OTG/Host charge. Samsung used to have a hub that it was doing the same but they stopped manufacturing it.